# card-io exception about :Please add -ObjC to 'Other Linker Flags' in your project settings

Tags: ios, swift, card.io

I didn't use CocoaPods add Core-io to my project
then I followed the correct step :

1. download the latest version: card.io-iOS-SDK-5.2.2
2. Add the CardIO directory to my Project
3. in the PROJECTS section, add -lc++ to Other Linker Flags
4. Add only these frameworks to my project :(Accelerate、AVFoundation、AudioToolbox、CoreMedia、MobileCoreServices)
5. confirm these two Build Settings are both enabled:(Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)、Link Frameworks Automatically)

and this is mySimpleCode:

```
//用户确认扫描信息
func userDidProvideCreditCardInfo(cardInfo: CardIOCreditCardInfo!, inPaymentViewController paymentViewController: CardIOPaymentViewController!) {
    if let card = cardInfo {
        labelResult.text = "卡号:\(card.cardNumber)\n过期年月:\(card.expiryYear)年\(card.expiryMonth)月\nCVV:\(card.cvv)"
    }
    paymentViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

begin scan:

```
//begin scan
@IBAction func startScan(sender: UIButton) {
    let cardVC = CardIOPaymentViewController(paymentDelegate: self)
    cardVC.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet
    presentViewController(cardVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and the following is Exception:

> 2015-11-26 13:06:05.623 ScanCard[17161:930434] +[NSObject testForObjCLinkerFlag]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x11107c170
>   2015-11-26 13:06:05.628 ScanCard[17161:930434] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CardIO-IncompleteIntegration', reason: 'Please add -ObjC to 'Other Linker Flags' in your project settings. (+[NSObject testForObjCLinkerFlag]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x11107c170)'
>   *** First throw call stack:

I tried to Add `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags`, but build failed.

Answer (score 2):

I added -l"CardIO" to Other Linker Flags and it works for me

Comment: Please elaborate more on your answer.

Comment: WORKED for me too. THX

Answer (score 0):

do as the image you see

[image]

hope help you

Comment: The @Gines answer works for me -l"CardIO"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Correct image displayed]
Just I don't know why caught Exception,but now it looks very nice.

Comment: me too, it is added but no success

Comment: The @Gines answer works for me -l"CardIO"